# Delphi. Модальное окно не блокируют главную форму

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Есть проект, с главным окном Form1

```
FormStyle = fsMDIForm
```

Оно создается посредством вызова

```
Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
```

Есть второе окно, которое должно блокировать все, пока пользователь не ответит на вопрос. Оно вызывается из главного таким кодом:

```
var F: TForm;
...
try
  F := TForm2.Create(Application.MainForm);
  F.ShowModal;
finally
  F.Free;
end;
```

В некоторых случаях второе окно "проваливается" под главное и не блокирует его, т.е. ведет себя не как модальное, а как обычное. Иногда то же самое происходит с диалогами, вызванными посредством `ShowMessage`.

Предполагаю, что у меня какие-то проблемы с главным окном, но вот какие - не могу понять.

Что можете посоветовать, куда копать, что проверять?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59828/discussion-on-question-by---delphi-----).

Answer (score 3):

Был уже почти правильный ответ, только одно но, не то свойство задели.
при динамическом создании элементов не присваивается родитель
Задайте его и будет вам счастье

```
ModalForm := TForm2.Create(Application.MainForm);
ModalForm.Parrent := MainForm;
ModalForm.ShowModal();
```

> > Что можете посоветовать, куда копать, что проверять?

Зы. Копать можно в обработчик сообщений, но много толку это вам не даст.
С главной формой проблема может быть только в нестандартном обработчике событий, проблемы в дочерней форме.

зыы. еще не указана версия среды, в D7\xe-5\7\8 только с такой проблемой сталкивался. (не считая описанного в другом ответе - ухода модальной формы "под" родительское окно, но блок на ввод при этом остается не тронутым).

Answer (score 0):

Во всех непонятных случаях нужно начать с воспроизведения ошибки/неадекватного поведения в новом пустом проекте. `FormStyle` здесь не играет никакой роли.

1. Создаем новый проект VCL Forms Application.
2. Добавляем новую форму в проект (Правой кнопкой мыши на проект в менеджере проектов: Add New -> VCL Form). На новой форме ничего не меняем. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. В свойствах проекта (Project -> Options -> Forms) убираем вторую форму из списка Auto-create forms.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. На первой форме добавляем обработчик OnClick.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. В раздел uses модуля с первой формой добавляем Unit2 и пишем обработчик OnClick.

Примерно такой:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TForm2.Create(Self) do
  try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

Все работает :)

Comment: Я за вас очень рад, что у вас все работает. Но мою проблему это не решает.

Comment: Логичный вывод из этого: Вы не в том месте ищете проблему.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Похоже, что Вы мало сталкивались с трудно-воспроизводимыми/плавающими багами, раз даёте ответ в стиле *"у меня всё работает"*. В том, что проблема реально существует можете убедиться, немного погуглив по фразе *modal form behind*. Аналогичный вопрос есть и на enSO: [Form is hidden behind other forms when ShowModal is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639125)

Comment: Вот тут вы ошибаетесь, мне часто приходится искать причины трудновоспроизводимых багов. Я нигде не говорил, что проблемы нет. И я не сомневаюсь, что она существует. Проблемы подобного рода обычно возникают при попытках манипулирования порядком отображения окон на экране или работой с визуальными компонентами не из основного потока.

Comment: Можете и дальше искать что не так с вашими окнами, только дело не в окнах. И `try` пишут после `Create`, а не до, как в вашем вопросе. Если `Create` не сработает, то код в секции `finally` бесполезен, т.к. освобождать нечего. Если в конструкторе случается exception, то компилятор сам вызовет деструктор.

Answer (score 0):

Установка свойства `PopupParent` должно решать проблему. Попробуйте такой код:

```
var
  VForm: TfrmModal;
begin
  VForm := TfrmModal.Create(nil);
  try
    VForm.PopupMode := pmAuto;
    VForm.PopupParent := Application.MainForm;
    VForm.Position := poMainFormCenter;
    VForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    VForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Я бы согласился с вами, если бы та же проблема не происходила и с `ShowMessage`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов А со мной не надо соглашаться или нет, надо просто изменить свой код с учётом моей рекомендации  и посмотреть, как будет вести себя программа и пройдёт ли баг. Проблема с `ShowMessage` может иметь совершенно другие причины и для него будет другое решение.

Answer (score 0):

С чем то подобным я сталкивался, когда пользователь переключается на другое приложение и возвращается обратно кликая мышкой на панели задач. В таком случае модального окошка может быть не видно, но оно все таки все равно блокирует ввод, оставляя пользователя в недоумении.

Чтобы не проваливалось дайте ему стиль FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;

Answer (score 0):

Читал где-то про следующее

```
if IsIconic(Application.Handle) then
    Application.Restore;
```